# Mock testing dependency injection object reference

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, visual-studio-2017

First time to create unit testing using mock. I'm having problem as I'm having error on object reference.

```
Mock<IAccount> mock = new Mock<IAccount>();
var testController = new AccountController(mock.Object);

IActionResult result = testController.Withdraw(1,100,"sample");
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToActionResult));
```

under my `AccountController` class on deposit method

```
var _account = _Iaccount.GetAccountById(id);
if (_account.Password != password)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Invalid Password!");
}
```

having error on `_Iaccount` as it was on the constructor.

thanks!

Comment: Could you please add more information? For instance the code of your controller. Furthermore, please attach the whole error message. Thanks

Comment: how can I register my repository interface? it seems I need to register it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must setup a mock object

```
var returnAccount = new Account { Name = "Ali" };
mock.Setup(s => s.GetAccountById(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(returnAccount);
```

`GetAccountById` will return `returnAccount`